# Pass a Variable from one file to another in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have added a custom field in a post (wp-themes/template/modal-question.php) like this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="anonymous" value="true"> 
<span><?php _e('Go Anonymous', ET_DOMAIN); ?></span>
```

and variable is

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['anonymous1']))
{ $post_author = 3; echo $post_author; } 
?>
```

I need to pass this varible '`$post_author`' (`$_GET` or `$_POST`) into another file post.php (Insert query into DB file), which resides in wp-includes/post.php

Please let me know if there's a way to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you asking about `wp_insert_post` function? it has `post_author` parameter to assign post to author.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

One time create this:

```
$GLOBALS['anonymous1'] = 'Your Value';
```

Then you get in any template of WordPress

```
echo $GLOBALS['anonymous1'];
```

**Edit:**

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['anonymous1'])) { 
  $GLOBALS['anonymous2'] = $_POST['anonymous1'];
  echo $GLOBALS['anonymous2'];
} 
?>
```

Comment: I'm actually looking to get this variable in the same template. Will that work?

Comment: Yes it will. Take a look and try it.

Comment: I don't quite get it. If I understand correctly, I should replace the 
<?php if(isset($_POST['anonymous1']))
{ $post_author = 3; echo $post_author; } 
?>
with 
<?php if(isset($GLOBALS['anonymous1']))
{ $post_author = 3; echo $post_author; } 
?>

Comment: I echoed the $GLOBALS['anonymous2'] in the post.php(wp-includes/post.php) . It should work right?

Comment: Yes because it is global variable. Pass this `anonymous2` to `author`.

Comment: Let me confirm one thing you want to pass some value to another template right ?

Comment: NO, pleas check my first comment.

Comment: What are the value you will get on this `$_POST['anonymous1']` ?

Comment: I want to alert a message when the checkbox is checked. So, I want to check if its selected using if(isset($_POST['anonymous1']

Comment: Ok got it so you use jquery to know that it checked or not then passing that value true to global and apply your condition. It will definitely work.